# java.lang.ExceptionInIntilizerError in main

Tags: java, android

My app crashes straight away with an exception
[image]

Here is the code of my main activity

```
package com.example.orientation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements myList.Communication {
    myList listFragment;
    Details detailsFragment;
    FragmentManager manager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        manager=getFragmentManager();
        listFragment = (myList) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);
        listFragment.setCommunicator(this);
    }

  @Override
    public void respond(int index) {
        detailsFragment = (Details) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);

        if (detailsFragment!=null && detailsFragment.isVisible()) {
            detailsFragment.changeData(index);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailActity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index",index);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried reading documentation but could not get how to solve this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: This error generally comes when you have some error in static blocks. Do you have any static block or method in your code?

Comment: I have an empty constructor and this code..

 public void setCommunicator(Communication comm){
        this.comm = comm;
    }
    public interface Communication{
        public void respond(int index);
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you have only added android support jar, you must add the whole Appcompat project to your workspace:

right click -> IMport -> Android -> Project from Existing Source

Then go to SDK Folder where you installed and find extras/android/support/v7/appcompat

and add this whole Library.

It seems like you are missing resources needed for ActionBarActivity